# W3C Validation of SRCSET

Tags: html, image, w3c-validation, srcset

W3C Validator is throwing an error on the following code:

```
<img alt="My Unique Alternative Text" class="news-image-left" height="480" src="/images/en-us/news/20140214-01.jpg" srcset="/images/en-us/news/20140214-01.jpg 1x, /images/en-us/news/20140214-01-mobile.jpg 640w" style="border-width: 0px;" title="A Unique Image" width="1420" itemprop="image">
```

The error is:

> Bad value /images/en-us/news/20140214-01.jpg 1x,
>   /images/en-us/news/20140214-01-mobile.jpg 640w for attribute srcset on
>   element img: No width specified for image
>   /images/en-us/news/20140214-01.jpg. (Because one or more image
>   candidate strings specify a width (e.g., the string for image
>   /images/en-us/news/20140214-01-mobile.jpg), all image candidate
>   strings must specify a width.)

So, how do I specify both an image for pixel density (1x) -- down the road I may want to do one for high-density displays (2x) and for displays less than 640 pixels wide?   That is, in a way that will make the W3C validator happy.

---

**UPDATE:**

Well, I tinkered around some more with it and now the validator is no longer complaining but it doesn't appear to be working right so I don't think I have won the battle yet.

I now have this:

```
<img alt="My Unique Alternative Text" class="news-image-left" height="480" src="/images/en-us/news/20140214-01.jpg" srcset="/images/en-us/news/20140214-01-mobile.jpg 320w" sizes="(min-width:640px) 1420px, 320px" style="border-width: 0px;" title="A Unique Image" width="1420" itemprop="image">
```

BUT, now on Chrome I am getting just the "-mobile" image, regardless of how wide my screen is.   I want it to display the full 1420px wide image on any display that is wider than 640px.

I am guessing I have just one thing out of place... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I may be blunt - no one really cares about W3C validation anymore. Especially since they're not the ones writing the HTML5 spec anyway.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Aren't they? They're the only ones who call it HTML5. The living standard is just HTML.

Comment: @alexander farkas answer below is the correct useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers only for your update:
The reason for this is, that the browser chooses one candidate from your `srcset`, the `src` attribute is used as a fallback. This means to get the larger candidate you need to also add it to your `srcset`:

```
<img srcset="/images/en-us/news/20140214-01-mobile.jpg 320w, /images/en-us/news/20140214-01.jpg 1420w" sizes="(min-width:640px) 1420px, 320px" />
```

I don't really know your image layout, but I doubt, that `sizes` is correct here. If this image is displayed fullwidth until 1420px your sizes attribute should look like this.

`sizes="(min-width: 1420px) 1420px, 100vw"`

or

`sizes="(max-width: 1420px) 100vw, 1420px"`

Additionally you should use more images. Note if you use the width descriptor the browser automatically handles the density for you (for retina devices). Use at least 640w, 980w/1024w, 1420w, 2048w.

Comment: I will give this a try.   I probably will eventually create additional images for the median sizes -- but baby steps.

Comment: Ok, well... with the above syntax, the desktop image now loads for wide screens.   But when I inspect the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools I see BOTH images are being requested and loaded.   

Why is this?

Comment: I can't duplicate the double image load issue anymore.   It must have been some weird caching thing?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer http://www.webkit.org/demos/srcset/ or https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/. Based on the w3c validator, if you specify width descriptor for one of the image candidate string, then you should use width descriptor for all of them.

Alternate option could be to use CSS media queries.

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with validation 2) The standard allows width values.

Comment: @Nisar https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/ was particularly helpful.   But the one thing I guess I missed amidst the the talk of peas and The Onion-esque drawings was how to correctly deal with pixel density.     While I am not using it right now, I would like to have the ability to create new images for higher density screens.   If the "w" and "vw" items are CSS-pixel based, then how do we deal with display-pixels?

Comment: w is not CSS pixel, it's image pixel. The browser takes care of high-density screens for you when using w/sizes. If you want to add a higher-density image, just add a bigger image to the set.