# How to show <picture>'s 2x image on retina mobile?

Tags: html

I'm trying to use `<picture>`and show `1x` or `2x` images depending on screen.

```
<picture class="general-info__photo">
        <source srcset="images/me2x.png" media="
                    only screen and ( min-resolution: 200dpi),
                    only screen and ( min-resolution: 1.25dppx)">
        <img src="images/me1x.png" alt="my photo">
    </picture>
```

And it works on my retina macbook, but I see `1x` image on iphone 5s. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeP5nKHpuyus4LcJwBHjR2aDC6m28FSD9e-5dCu2Kl7rglEpVflQ">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsPqgViwHdLlxPgRl6uC1NCe5t8jxyq9-m1gM6S3b6yy6jrqLa">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the wflag we can tell the browser that we have the same image available in different widths. The width is similar to using the `max-width` CSS property in media queries.

```
<img
  src="/images/me2x.png"
  alt="my photo"
  srcset="/images/me2x-medium.png 1024w,
               /images/me2x-large.png 2048w,
               /images/me2x.png 800w"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, works. But w3 validator says Error: When the srcset attribute has any image candidate string with a width descriptor, the sizes attribute must also be present.

Comment: @user2950602 see the update here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788868/w3c-validation-of-srcset , hope it solves the error now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<picture class="general-info__photo">
            <img sizes="160px"
                 src="images/me.png"
                 alt="my photo"
                 srcset="images/me2x.png 320w, images/me.png 160w"
            />
        </picture>
```