# Invalid HTML (sizes and srcset)

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5.2.4

In the HTML valdiator (https://validator.w3.org/) I have checked my site.

This error troubles me:

```
Error: The sizes attribute may be specified only if the srcset attribute is also present.

From line 320, column 9; to line 320, column 576

>↩                              <img width="65" height="65" src="http://ved/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/7aa97b86-ca24-11e9-9824-fa163…9/10/7aa97b86-ca24-11e9-9824-fa163e074e61-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 65px) 100vw, 65px" /><noscr
```

There are a lot of sucm errors. I have tried to find "sizes" in my IDE (Find in Path), and failed. Well such there are some. If it is not in wp-admin, I put a breakpoint. Well, I failed to make the debugger stop.

Could you help me localize the problem. I mean could you give me an instruction what to find (src, sizes, img or what), where to find (in the whole project, in the theme or something), in which case to put a breakpoint (in wp-content, wp-admin or else).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below solution : src will use any of image src set

See here: [W3C Validation of SRCSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788868/w3c-validation-of-srcset)

Comment: I've had a look at the solution you refer to. Frankly speaking, I don't understand you at all. Could you clarify: where to look what is the solution and how can it help me? In their case srcset was initially there.